# How to pass only the value of controller variable as argument in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to pass the extracted latitude and longitude from the google maps autocomplete API to a function that updates the map based on those coordinates.

How do i pass the value of the variables {{details1.geometry.location.lat()}} and {{details1.geometry.location.lng()}} as arguments for the updateMap() function in ng-blur="updateMap()"

```
<ion-content padding="true" class="has-header" ng-controller = "pollutionMapCtrl">

            <label class="item item-input" id="address-input" name="address">
                    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
                     <input id = "Autocomplete" type="text" ng-autocomplete ng-model = "result1" details = "details1" options = "options1" ng-blur="updateMap()">
            </label>

            <div>result: {{result1}}</div>
            <div>lat: {{details1.geometry.location.lat()}}</div>
            <div>long: {{details1.geometry.location.lng()}}</div>
```

controller file

```
.controller('pollutionMapCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.updateMap = function (lat,lng) {
    $scope.map = { center: { latitude: lat, longitude: lng }, zoom: 8 };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass arguments to functions the same way you do with normal function in Javascript:

```
ng-blur="updateMap(details1.geometry.location.lat(), details1.geometry.location.lng())"
```